# Inserting crosscutting c++ code via swig %exception directive

Tags: python, c++, swig

I would like to insert a piece of code (say a crosscutting c++ function call) before all the actual method invocations in the swig generated wrapper code. I have used the %exception directive in my .i file  and ended up getting the following wrapper code generated

```
some_crosscutting_c++_function_call();
try {
  {
    SWIG_PYTHON_THREAD_BEGIN_ALLOW;// release GIL
    actual_c++_function_call();
    SWIG_PYTHON_THREAD_END_ALLOW;// acquire GIL
  }
}
catch(some exception) {
  ......
}
```

But what I want is the following

```
try {
  {
    SWIG_PYTHON_THREAD_BEGIN_ALLOW;//release GIL
    some_crosscutting_c++_function_call();
    actual_c++_function_call();
    SWIG_PYTHON_THREAD_END_ALLOW;//acquire GIL
  }
}
catch(some exception) {
  ......
}
```

The crosscutting function call doesn't need GIL, hence I want it to be called after the GIL is released. Is there a way to have a hook just before actual_c++_function_call() and after SWIG_PYTHON_THREAD_BEGIN_ALLOW ?